# Special characters dissapeared when moving wordpress

Tags: wordpress, character, move

I moved a wordpress site to a new host.

Everything worked perfect on the old host. I've moved alot of wordpress sites before and I've never had this problem.

All special characters such as å ä ö is replaced by a �.
UTF-8 in wp-config, meta, database etc.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

to your .htaccess

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: what does your http-header return? which charset

Comment: And you are sure that the DB is using the correct charset?